# Database Insertion Failed

Tags: android, sqlite

My program contains a database with `name= countable`. First it contained only  3 columns and it was >working. Then I inserted a new column named `countevent` with variable name KEY_EVENT.Then after the >program shows an error as the column name `countevent` does not exist. pls help me to find the a >soluton.

> FirstActivity.java contains the following code.

```
class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String datevalue = date.getText().toString();
            String Userselectvalue = userSelection.getText().toString();
            String Userevent = edittext.getText().toString();
            SQLiteDatabase  db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC, Userselectvalue);
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT, Userevent);
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE,datevalue);
            db.insert(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
            db.close();
```

> ClassdbOpenHelper

```
package example.showevent1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class classdbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DESC = "countdesc";
    public static final String KEY_EVENT = "countevent";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "countdate";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "countdb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "countable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public classdbOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       /* db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
        //KEY_COUNTED + " INTEGER " +
        KEY_DESC + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
        KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                ); */
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
                + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT " + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    String getContact() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        int _id = 0;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE , new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC,KEY_EVENT, KEY_DATE}, KEY_ROWID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(_id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
      String  place = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("KEY_EVENT"));
        return place;
    }
}
```

> logat

```
08-05 07:43:26.918: E/SQLiteLog(838): (1) table countable has no column named countevent
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838): Error inserting countdesc=Yalahanka countevent=hh countdate=8-5-2013
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table countable has no column named countevent (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO countable(countdesc,countevent,countdate) VALUES (?,?,?)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at example.showevent1.FirstActivity$clicker.onClick(FirstActivity.java:148)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-05 07:43:26.978: E/SQLiteDatabase(838):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed "," sign in your Database Creation definition between your columns:

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
            + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT, " + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT " + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your DB version then install it. If it does not work then uninstall the apps then try to install it.Check your sqlite table creation query syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same DataBase Name then you need to add new Column in onupgrade method , if you are giving a new name to database then you create table in oncreate.

db.execSQL("create table DATABASE_TABLE(KEY_ROWID Integer primary key, KEY_DESC text," +
                    "KEY_EVENT text,KEY_DATE  text);");

Hope this will help you. No need to give +"" everywhere, as it make more confusion regarding opening and closing quotes("").

Thanks